# Php move_uploaded_file add another folder

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, directory

I was wondering how I would add on to this line of code to upload the image to `photos/` , and `/mobile/photos` ? So how would I add `/mobile/photos` to the script?

```
$place_file = move_uploaded_file( 
    $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], 
    "photos/".$newname);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "photos/$newname")) {
    copy("photos/$newname", "mobile/photos/$newname");
}
```

Comment: This is the better one using string interpolation. The second one uses useless concats with dbl. quotes. Using single quotes in the second answer would make it equal again (but this is a very tiny detail ;))

Comment: @marioMueller depends on how you write & how you look at it, i find it as a more readable form, which you find useless.. :)

Comment: it wont copy it into the other folder :( im using hostmonster... and it will post the picture to photos/ but not to mobile/photos/ which is a subdomain...

Comment: @Sudhir using single quotes on your example would make it equally performant. Double quotes are only useful for string interpolation and there is still a performance difference.

Comment: Have you set the folder read/write/execute privileges correctly?

Comment: but its not :( it wont copy it to the folder @MartyMcVry

Comment: $newname = uniqid().".jpg";
                        $place_file = move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "photos/".$newname);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "photos/$newname")) {
    copy("photos/$newname", "mobile/photos/$newname");
}

Comment: @Glenn You are moving the uploaded file, **and then you're trying to move it again!** Only one *move* will work!

Comment: oh ? so how do i do it ? @deceze

Comment: @Glenn The complete code is in my answer. You simply don't need the `$place_file = move_uploaded_file(...)` line.

Answer (score 0):

you could move_uploaded_file to first then [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) to second folder, like:

```
if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "photos/".$newname) ) {
   //copy to mobile/photos
   copy("photos/".$newname, "mobile/photos/".$newname);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) the file using php:

```
copy("photos/$newname", "mobile/photos/$newname");
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple just use the [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) PHP function. But first confirm that file exist before attempting to copy because copying might fail based a number of reasons

Here is a sample code:

```
if ($success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], 
                                  "photos/$newname") )   
{
    copy("photos/$newname", "mobile/photos/$newname");
}else{

 // error occurred
}
```